# Add or Import Metadata to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, metadata

Is there a way to add metadata to a shapefile in QGIS?

I have the shapefile and an XML metadata file and I want to import in shapefile.

Comment: You could try the plugin Qsphere... its version 2.6.5 is very stable and works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a plugin in QGIS called Metatools that can read/write metadata in ISO19115 format.

Comment: Can import to?.

Comment: Not sure.  I was able to write metadata which was saved as an ISO19115 xml file.  From the plugin author's announcement, the tool is very much beta.

Comment: Metatools does have an "Import metadata" option.

Also, both MetaTools and MetaEdit plugins are listed as "experimental," so to install them you have to go to the Python Plugin Installer Options page and click "Show all plugins, even those marked as experimental."